# Adjusting my adjacent div height when my current div height changes due to focusout validation messages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I need advice on how to hook into the event- when mvc data annotation validation messages gets rendered on focus out of current textbox.  If I use the focusout event for that textbox and set adjacent div height, the new height does not consider the text from the validation message the and the adjacent div's height ends up being shorter, any help on how to solve this would be much appreciated